# bootstrap-select option list only as long as underlying component

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow, bootstrap-select

I hope I can explain this clearly.  I have a table presenting a list of data in a thymeleaf template.  This table's header is a form that is used to filter its content.  The issue i have will manifest itself only if the table's content is very short, say only one record.  Here's some code to show what it looks like :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<form name="fiterScanCodes" th:action="@{'/scanCodes/search'}" method="POST">
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-dark">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Scan Code</th>
                <th>Med</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="scanCodeFilter" name="scanCodeFilter" th:value="${scanCodeFilter}" 
                        placeholder="Search Scan Code" onchange="this.form.submit()"/>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="medFilter" name="medFilter" th:value="${medFilter}"
                        onchange="this.form.submit()" data-live-search="true" title="Select Med"> 
                        <option value="">Search Med</option>
                        <option th:each="med : ${meds}" th:value="${med.id}" 
                            th:text="${med.toString()}" th:selected="${med.id == medFilter}">
                            </option>
                    </select>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each = "scanCode : ${scanCodes}">
                <td th:text = "${scanCode.scanCode}"></td>
                <td th:text = "${scanCode.med.toString()}"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
```

The problem i have is that the visible portion of the options is only ever as long as the table itself :

[image]

As the table gets larger, I can see more and more of the options until it finally appears completely :

[image]

What controls this behavior and how can I have the full option list display all the time?  I tried to set the overflow property to visible for the selectpicker class and that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I find my answer 2 minutes after writing this post while trying semi-random things!  My attempts to set the overflow property were heading in the right direction but i was incorrectly applying it to the selectpicker class.  The overflow property needs to be set on the underlying containers and not the component itself.  The below CSS fixed it :

```
.table-responsive
{
    overflow: visible;
}
```